# Question on Fulton 6.16

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am trying to solve problem 6.16 from Fulton’s Algebraic Curves:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of varieties, $X’ \subset X$, $Y’ \subset Y$ subvarieties (open or closed). Assume $f(X’) \subset Y’$. Then the restriction of $f$ to $X’$ is a morphism from $X’$ to $Y’$.

I know that any variety is isomorphic to an open subvariety of a projective variety, so $X$ is isomorphic to an open subvariety of a projective variety $S$ and $Y$ of a projective variety $T$. A projective variety is a finite union of affine varieties, so $S=\bigcup S_i$ with $S_i \cong S \cap U_i$ and $T_i \cong T \cap V_i$, $S_i$ and $T_i$ affine varieties. For $X$ and $Y$ this reduces to a finite union of quasi-affine varieties, so $X=\bigcup X_i$ and $Y=\bigcup Y_i$. I now want to apply problem 6.14:

> Let $X$, $Y$ be varieties, $f: X \to Y$ a mapping. Let $X = \bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha$, $Y = \bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha$ with $U_\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ open subvarieties, and suppose $f(U_\alpha) \subset V_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$.(a) Show that $f$ is a morphism iff. each restriction $f_\alpha: U_\alpha \to V_\alpha$ of $f$ is a morphism.

So I need that $f(X_i) \subset Y_i$ for all $i$, so if $x \in X_i = X' \cap U_i$, this reduces to $f(U_i) \subset V_i$, since $f(X') \subset Y'$ is given. Why exactly is this the case, because this boils down to a polynomial map between $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $\mathbb{A}^m$ by dehomogenizing $U_i$, $V_i$ resp.?
In the following I can then apply problem 2.9 (since the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are affine and therefore a morphism is the same as a polynomial map)

> Let $\varphi: V \to W$ be a polynomial map of affine varieties, $V’ \subset V$, $W’ \subset W$ subvarieties. Suppose $\varphi(V’) \subset W’$. (…) (b) Show that the  restriction of $\varphi$ gives a polynomial map from $V’$ to $W’$.

and using 6.14 again I can deduce the restriction of $f$ to $X’$ is a morphism.

Comment: Please include your definitions and the statements from the book that you're referring to - your question is not super understandable without these pieces of information.

Comment: @KReiser I am referring to: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. Leaving this information behind a link will lessen the chance that you get an answer, though, so it's in your own best interests to add it to your question.